# Public keys and Keystore don't match

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore, keytool

Following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742554/java-lang-exception-public-keys-in-reply-and-keystore-dont-match) , based on the accepted answer, the reason behind it is because the SSL certificate was generated for a completely different key pair.

But I don't think I generated it with a different key pair.

this is how I did it.

generate keystore:

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore pbsks.keystore
```

generate CSR:

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file csr.csr -keystore pbsks.keystore
```

use the generated csr to request certificate, then I received the file.

import the root ca, intermed and issued cert.

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore pbsks.keystore -trustcacerts -file root.crt

keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore pbsks.keystore -trustcacerts -file intermed.crt

keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore pbsks.keystore -trustcacerts -file issuedcert.crt.pem
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the key and the csr file from pbsks.keystore, but you are importing the generated certs to tomcat.keystore.

Comment: Actually, it should be like that really.

Comment: Found the problem, I really thought pem file is the issued cert but I was wrong. Pem file is the intermediate certificate.

Comment: Yeah, But I ran into another problem  lol.
It says connection is not secured but I already installed all certs and it was okay.

I was thinking maybe because my domain name and Common name in my CSR did not match?

Comment: This post can help you with that: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175786/is-it-required-to-have-the-same-domain-name-and-common-name-for-ssl-certificate